# Summarise a nested list

Tags: r, list

If I have a list of lists like:

```
pets = list(list("Shoji", "cat", 18), list("Hanako", "dog", 15), list("Sachiko", "alligator", 7), list("Toby", "dog", "12"))
```

How do I put the names of the animals into different animal categories and sort the same animals into the same categories?

```
$cat
[1] "Shoji"

$dog
[1] "Hanako" "Toby"  

$alligator
[1] "Sachiko"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tapply`:

```
tapply(X = sapply(pets, `[[`, 1), 
       INDEX = sapply(pets, `[[`, 2), 
       FUN = paste)
# $alligator
# [1] "Sachiko"
# 
# $cat
# [1] "Shoji"
# 
# $dog
# [1] "Hanako" "Toby"
```